# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: <include /> can only be used inside of a ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

Im new at developing with Android Studio. So this is the problem:
I open a new project and before even touching or adding a code I get this:

"Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering:  can only be used inside of a ViewGroup"

So I use Nexus 4 as ADV (as a default), so I tried other ADVs and get the same warning. The only thing that gives no warning is Android Wear Round and Square.

Anyone who can help me? Below is the layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="Hi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the layout resource that has the `<include/>` tag.

Comment: That's the weird part, there is no <include/> or I cant see it :/

Answer (score 3):

In styles.xml add Base before Theame.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Please explain , it helped me. +1

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the people who tried to help me. I've solved my problem and want to share with you for the case other may encounter the same problem. Actually it was very simple I've found it by accident :D

From the bar above choose Build > Make Module 'app'

That's it :D this fixed my problem